# Microsoft Excel worksheet function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What formula should I use if:

```
Cell:
A1 = 10, 
B1 = 1, 
C1 = B1/C1 = 0.1
```

D1 should show how many more it is needed to be added to both B1 and C1 (same amount) so that B1/C1 will less than or equal to 0.05

Comment: Just add -0.95 to both B1 and C1. C1 will be negative but that is the only way to add identical amounts to B1 and C1 and make B1 <= 0.05.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly, you wanted to display a number in D1 which shows how much you wanted to add in B1 to get C1 less than or equal to 0.05. if it is correct, use the below formula in D1.

```
=IF(C1>0.05,-(C1-0.05)*A1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

**D1** formula should go like this:

```
=(B1-(B1*0,96))/(C1-(B1*0,96))*(-1)
```

This will give you correct output for most cases, if you increase **0.96** constant to **0.97** that would suffice even more number of cases.